# Primefaces autocomplete: select first item on space key

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using a `<p:autoComplete multiple="true" ... />` primefaces component.

I want that each time the user press the space key, the first item in the dropdown is added in the selected items list.

Is-it possible ?

**form.xhtml**

```
<p:autoComplete
    value="#{userBean.addSelectedRepositories}"
    completeMethod="#{userBean.onCompleteRepository}"
    itemLabel="#{r.path}"
    itemValue="#{r}"
    var="r"
    converter="entityConverter"
    forceSelection="false"
    multiple="true"
    >
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{r.path}" />
    </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

**UserBean.java**

```
public List<Repository> onCompleteRepository(String query) {
    return repositoryService.search(query);
}
```

So for example, the items are `'one', 'two', 'three'`

If the user enter one followed by the space key, I need that the one element be selected.

Comment: Yes this is possible with some jquery

Comment: Well, if it is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: Start [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+detect+pressed+spacebar), contains lots of info. Secondly inspect the javascript api of the autocomplete component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the solution I finally get:

```
<p:autoComplete
    value="#{userBean.addSelectedRepositories}"
    completeMethod="#{userBean.onCompleteRepository}"
    itemLabel="#{r.path}"
    itemValue="#{r}"
    var="r"
    converter="entityConverter"
    forceSelection="false"
    multiple="true"
    widgetVar="autocomplete"
    >
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{r.path}" />
    </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

And then I added a little javascript at the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('input[aria-autocomplete=listbox]').keyup(function(e) {
        var k = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (k == 32) {
            if (PF('autocomplete').items.length > 0) {
                PF('autocomplete').items.filter('.ui-state-highlight').trigger('click');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The solution is not perfect as I put the component name inside my javascript.
And this solution does not handle the paste event so I cannot convert pasted items into selected values.